# Extra Argument 'duration' in call

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

my project is complaining that there is an "Extra argument 'duration' in call". Here is where it is occurring

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    workout = Workout(title: "Luke's Workout Plan", exercisePeriods: [
        ExercisePeriod(duration: 5, intensity: .High), //error
        ExercisePeriod(duration: 1, intensity: .Low),  //error
        ExercisePeriod(duration: 5, intensity: .High),  //error
        ExercisePeriod(duration: 1, intensity: .Low)  //error
        ]
    )
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

These variables are defined here:

```
struct ExercisePeriod: Printable {
let duration: NSTimeInterval = 0
let intensity: Intensity = .High

// TODO: Make ExercisePeriod loggable
var description: String {
    return "\(intensity.rawValue) for \(duration) seconds"
}
}
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning values to `duration` and `intensity` in the definition of the `ExercisePeriod` structure.  `let` only lets you assign a value once, so you can't assign another value in the constructor.  To fix this, either define `duration` and `intensity` with `var` **or** remove the default values for `duration` and `intensity`.

Comment: @JohnHarding, did this solve your problem? If so, please accept my answer by ticking the checkmark to the left.